# Test cases for JPQL and normal Queries

Tags: java, integration-testing, jpql, spring-boot-test

In my project we are caching the data of a table where we use `@NamedQuery` for fetching the data (Hibernate queries) and we are also using `@NamedNativeQueries` and my code is like that

```
@SpringBootTest
public class NonPolygonIntegeration {
@Autowired
private Repository localRepository;

@MockBean
ServicePropertiesRepository servicePropertiesRepository;

@MockBean
CacheService alendarCacheService;

@Autowired
OlygonService olygonService;
@Test
@Order(1)
@Sql(scripts = {"/sqls/mdm.sql", "/sqls/p.sql","/sqls/q.sql",
        "/sqls/x.sql",
        "/sqls/y.sql",
        "/sqls/z.sql"
}, config = @SqlConfig(encoding = "utf-8"))
void testGetAllActiveCurrencies_forDataPresentInDb() {


}
}
```

"""

I have data in my local database for all the corresponding tables in use.
query which will get in use are

```
@Query("Select * FROM Properties WHERE id.Code =:serviceCode AND (endDate IS NULL OR endDate >= CURRENT_DATE)")
```

and other is

```
select * from empoyee_table where employee_id = :id
```

How to handle such scenario?